# Trying to display text, but no luck. However, I check my console and see empty divs with p tags. App is not breaking

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am in the process of working on a joke app, which I am building from scratch by myself with no tutorial. Right now, there is a component `SportsJokesApi`, that pulls in the data from a local json folder (SportsJokesData) I created. This is how it is set up:

```
const SportsJokesData = [
    {
        id: "1",
        question: "What did the baseball glove say to the ball?",
        answer: "Catch ya later!"

    }
]
export default Sports Jokes Data
```

On the landing page, when the user selects the Sports Jokes category, they will be taken to a new page which will display jokes related to sports.  Right now, you need to click the button `(Click here for a joke)` in order for the first joke to display. I would love for the first random joke to already be displaying when the user selects this category and gets taken to that page for the first time.

This is how I have the component set up. In my initial approach I created a separate function called `getInitialJoke`, which returns a random joke. Then in the render, I created a variable called const `{initialJoke}` which is `this.getInitialJoke();` and then the joke would be displayed. Since state update is asynchronous, I did some safety checking by using `initialjoke?.answer`. When I go back and run the app, no joke appears and the text does not show up. However, I do see new divs with empty p tags on console.  Does anyone know what could be wrong and how I can fix this? Again, I want a joke to already be displaying.  The way it is set up in this component, you have to click on the `Click Here for a Joke` button in order to see the first joke.

```
import React from 'react'
import SportsJokesData from '../data/SportsJokesData';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './Buttons.css';
const initialState = {
  randomJoke: {}
};

class SportsJokesApi extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.getRandomJoke = this.getRandomJoke.bind(this);
    this.state = initialState;
  }

  getInitialJoke() {
    return SportsJokesData[(SportsJokesData.length * Math.random()) << 0];
  }
  getRandomJoke() {
    this.setState({
      randomJoke: SportsJokesData[(SportsJokesData.length * Math.random()) << 0]
    });
  }


  render() {
    const {randomJoke} = this.state;
    const {initialJoke} = this.getInitialJoke();

    return (
      <React.Fragment >
        <div>
          <p>{initialJoke?.question}</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>{initialJoke?.answer}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="flex">
          <p>{randomJoke.question}</p> 
        </div>
        <div className="flex">
          <p>{randomJoke.answer}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="flex">
          <button class="btn joke" onClick = {this.getRandomJoke}>Click here for joke </button> 
        </div>
        <div className="flex">
          <Link to="/ProgrammingJokes">
            <button className="btn programming">Programming Jokes</button>
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div className="flex">
          <Link to="/DadJokes">
            <button className="btn dad">Dad Jokes</button>
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div className="flex">
          <Link to="/SpanishJokes">
            <button className="btn spanish">Chistes en ñ</button>
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div className="flex">
          <Link to="/">
            <button className="btn home">Home Page</button>
          </Link>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment >
    );
  }
}
export default SportsJokesApi;
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could call the initialJoke() function in one of the React lifeCycle Events, for example with something like this:

```
// Add this to your code fellow. 
     componentDidMount() {
      this.getInitialJoke();
   }
```

For more information on the life cycle events and how they work, have a look at this great article, buddy.

[React: Component Lifecycle Events](https://medium.com/@joshuablankenshipnola/react-component-lifecycle-events-cb77e670a093)

Comment: Yes I did the same. Or if you need specific content you can use 'state' variable to store it.